# Is there a phrase for "I want A with or without B"?

Tags: phrases

> "How would I go about easily explaining that I'm looking for one thing
>   on it's own, OR with the inclusion of a second thing? Not a "And/or"
>   or "Either/or" situation, but a "Thing A, with or without Thing B". Is
>   there a specific short word/phrase to depict that scenario?"

Was a question posed to me by a friend that I couldn't answer, the only way I could think was to say was what he had already put "I want A with or without B", is there another phrase that could be used in this scenario?

Comment: If you really don't care if it includes B, just say "I want A". Otherwise, you can say  "I want A, preferably with B". I can't think of any other scenarios.

Comment: It's not "I wants ...".  I want / you want / he wants / they want.

Comment: @HotLicks Wow I totally didn’t notice that, edited now thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I want A, regardless of B.** or **I want A, irrespective of B.**

Stating explicitly that your want of A is regardless of B communicates an especial irreverence for B but if this is not your intention, it is unnecessary. @JonLarby made a particularly useful comment that "with or without B" or any equivalent can be dropped while maintaining the core meaning and I recommend this course of action if your intent is not to communicate emotions, or lack thereof, about B.

Comment: That certainly seems to make the most sense, thanks to both you and @JonLarby